# why does the invocation of a make "target" result in an extra command as opposed to invokation of "target.o"

Tags: makefile

i have a makefile rule that looks like the following:

```
queue.o: queue/queue.cpp
     g++ -Wall -g -c queue/queue.cpp
```

and when i invoke "make queue" it runs the command resulting in a queue.o but it also runs another command

```
g++   queue.o   -o queue
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file queue: Is a directory
```

the question is. why is an extra command run when i invoke without extension? it obviously knows which command to invoke because it matches "queue" to "queue.o" target, but then goes on to try and make another object.

Comment: how is your `queue` target ?

Answer (score 0):

GNU make has a bunch of built-in [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html) that it will use to try to create a target when the Makefile doesn't give any way to do so.

In your case, the rule for "linking a single object file" is being invoked to create `queue` from `queue.o`, since you didn't provide any rule to do so in the Makefile explicitly. That rule runs the linker, which is assumed by default to be `/usr/bin/ld`.

Comment: so when i invoke "make queue", even though it knows to run the command in "queue.o" target, it will go ahead and try to use the created object to also try and create a "queue" target? it seems redundant if it knows already to use my target, why would it go and make another target? i can understand it trying to do so if it hadn't run the command in the "queue.o" target; its almost as if its contradicting itself (it found a target it works with, but then goes on to do another one?)

Comment: It expects that you wouldn't just compile an object file and then not do anything with it... otherwise what was the point of compiling it? Anyway, I feel like people can only speculate since you didn't post the whole Makefile; who knows what else is in there.

Comment: @DevilsDulcimer Make is trying to make a `queue` target because you _told_ it to make a `queue` target by running the command `make queue`... does that clarify things at all? If not, I'm afraid I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: @David_Z oh ok. since i did "make queue", it naturally looks for a queue.o and finds my queue.o target right? it has nothing to do then with a shorthand notation for invoking? it has instead to do with the fact that its trying to build "queue" so naturally it looks for a "queue.o" and instead finds a target to create it? Then it goes on to try and use it to build queue? i originally was confused that since it found my target, then why did it need a second command;so this is a chain effect where there's auto lookup.